# How to override third party module \view\frontend\templates\ from my custom theme using prefrence?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I am using a third-party module, I am added one extra feature to it, after upgrade the extension all my changes removed right, how to handle this situation, i mean how to override third-party module from my theme,

eg. I am updated one feature in model **app\code\Magefan\Blog\Model\Post.php** How to add this update from my custom theme.

Comment: if it is .php file you can't override using theme you have to create your custom module and then override that class

Comment: Like model how to add app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\widget\recent.phtm files in prefrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you should override that class from your own module.

Create a Magento 2 module (lear here: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) and then add this in your `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magefan\Blog\Model\Post" type="NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Magefan\Post" />
</config>
```

Now your class `NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Magefan\Post.php`

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Magefan;

class Post extends \Magefan\Blog\Model\Post {

    public function yourNewFunction()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, if you call this function from your theme, then it should work.

Comment: How to add my following 2 files  : app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\widget\recent.phtml &  app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\post\view\relatedposts.phtml,

Comment: To override you can create a new folder/file in your theme, `app/design/frontend/Your_Theme/ThemeName/Magefan_Blog/templates/widget/recent.phtml`. The idea is to place all the files inside `Magefan_Blog` with the same folder structure. And clear your cache.

Comment: Model is rewrite using a custom module, for templates inside the theme folder, is it the correct way?

Comment: Yes, that way, when that module is disabled, the theme will know and will not care about it.